# Existential and Universal Quantification (Formal Proofs)

Tags: logic

Is $\neg\forall x:X.r\equiv\exists x:X.\neg r$ in formal proofs?

My reasoning behind this is making use of $\exists$ and $\forall$ quantification and then making use of the double negation rule, however I am unsure whether or not you are able to do the following in formal proofs:

$\neg\forall x:X.r$

$\neg\neg\exists x:X.\neg r$

$\exists x:X.\neg r$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In classical logic, $\forall$ is equivalent to $\neg \exists \neg$ and $\exists$ is equivalent to $\neg \forall \neg$, in the sense that
$$\forall x \varphi(x) \leftrightarrow \neg \exists x \neg \varphi(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \exists x \varphi(x) \leftrightarrow \neg \forall x \neg \varphi(x)$$
hold for all formulae $\varphi$. In fact, often only one of the quantifiers is taken to be primitive, and the other is defined in this way.

Ultimately it depends on which set of axioms you're using. In any case, it's valid (unless you're doing something like constructive logic), it's just a matter of how you can justify it.